# How to make sure two setInterval() will not affect each other?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have 2 setInterval function (okay guys, sorry, I thought the code inside may be redundant and will make the question become localized :/ but anyway, here it is:

```
$('#armStatus').click(function(){
  armingloop = setInterval(function () {
  if ($checkbox.is(':checked ')) {
    $.post('/request', {
      key_pressed: "arming_status"
    }).done(function (reply) {
      $arm.empty().append("<h3>The Arming Status is " + reply + "</h3>").show();
      $arm.show();
    });
  } else {
    $arm.hide();
  }
}, 3000);
});
```

and

```
$('#monitor').click(function () {
  bigloop = setInterval(function () {
  var checked = $('#status_table tr [id^="monitor_"]:checked');
  if (checked.index() === -1 || checked.length === 0) {
    clearloop(bigloop);
    $('#monitor').button('enable');
  } else {
    //$('#monitor').button('enable'); //enable the monitor button
    (function loop(i) {
      //monitor element at index i
      monitoring($(checked[i]).parents('tr'));
      //delay of 3 seconds
      setTimeout(function () {
        //when incremented i is less than the number of rows, call loop for next index
        if (++i < checked.length) loop(i);
      }, 3000);
    }(0)); //start with 0
  }
}, index * 3000); //loop period
```

});

```
 function clearloop(loopname){
          bigloop= window.clearInterval(loopname);
     }
```

Both will be triggered by a different selector. I observe that when the `bigloop` is activated, and `armingloop` is also activated at a later time, the status update function `monitoring` in my `bigloop` is affected (e.g. status reply is captured by wrong element.)

Note that I have a `setTimer` as well.

**My question here is, how can i make sure any 2 `setInterval`s are isolated and will not affect each other?**

Comment: What's inside `armingloop`?

Comment: Can you show us the contents of the armingloop?  Also, is clearloop a custom method or do you mean clearInterval?

Comment: @JosephtheDreamer just posting and append some text in a div

Comment: I don't get it. Are you saying that `armingloop` does something to the element? Then this is a bug in `armingloop`. How is that related to `setInterval`?

Comment: @Maloric opps yes, i'll add that right away

Comment: JavaScript is single-threaded, the functions will never run parallel.

Comment: @EaterOfCorpses But timers could run out of order, especially when there are two of them and have different intervals.

Comment: hey guys, i've added full codes. :) thanks for any help!

Comment: @freakish sorry for the ambiguity just now. my problem is that i have 2 `setInterval` and 1 `setTimeout`. when 2 of them are running consequently, things are messing up. i've edited the question as well. you can see the interval for the `armingloop` and the `setTimeout` is the same.

Comment: `setInterval` cannot be guaranteed to run at the correct time even when there's only one of them. If some other JS code is blocking execution, the interval event will queue up and wait its turn. If interval events are themselves the cause of the block, this can lead to the timing of events becoming quite unpredictable.

Comment: @Spudley Oh! that probably explains why if the interval hasnt been set, and a function which include `clearInterval` is called, it will stuck there forever? any alternative to do a loop instead of `setinterval`?

Comment: @yvonnezoe - [this page](http://bonsaiden.github.io/JavaScript-Garden/#other.timeouts) has more info about the possible issue with blocking code and `setInterval`.

Comment: Please show us that `monitoring` function and how exactly it interferes with the `armingloop`.

Comment: @Bergi umm how i can show you? the function is posting to a python function which communicates with external device.

Comment: OK, but how does that interfere with the `arming_status` request?

Comment: @Bergi well, both of the function are posting to the same python function, thus when it receives a reply, my program will do a check (in python) and return back the reply to the calling function (in jQuery). That is when 2 or more of the replies get confused.

Answer (score 3):

You simply can't as they have no guarantee of order. They are added to an event queue together with other events (incl. repaints etc.), and which ever comes first is called.

A better implementation would be in your main loop to throw a `CustomEvent` which your monitor is listening to.

Simplified:

```
// global flag for monitoring
var isMonitoring = true,
    armingloop;

// the function we use to update monitor.
// This will be called every time we send an event
function updateMonitor(e) {
    /* ... update ... */
    // ie. e.detail.mydata 
}

// Start listening to 'monitor' event. If received, call
// the function above (only reference the function).
window.addEventListener('monitor', updateMonitor, false);

// The main loop. Self-triggering for loop by calling
// setTimeout.
// Do the stuff you need and then, if monitor is
// enabled create an event and dispatch (send) it.
function loop() {

    /* ... main stuff ... */

    // do we monitor? 
    if (isMonitoring) {

        // something need to be updated on monitor so
        // create an event
        var myEvent = new CustomEvent('monitor', {
            detail: {
                /* here you can provide needed data for monitor */
                "mydata": data /*, other data */
            },
            /* If you don't need to send any data in particular,
               just leave detail empty like this:
               detail: {},
            */
            bubbles: false,
            cancelable: true
        });

        // send event to anyone who listens..
        window.dispatchEvent(myEvent);
    }

    //here you can use a use a flag to stop the loop,
    //f.ex. if 'isLooping' === true then setTimeout...
    armingloop = setTimeout(loop, 3000);
}

function toggleMonitor() {
    // Call this from the toggle button, or modify to
    // reflect checkbox-status etc...
    isMonitoring = !isMonitoring;
}

//start everything:
loop();
```

I changed the example a bit from `setInterval` to `setTimeout` to avoid stacking/blocking. Also keep in mind that Javascript is single-threaded (with a few exceptions that are not relevant here). For this reason `setTimeout` is a better choice (call it from inside the loop).

Comment: first time seeing all those codes. :O do you mean at any point of time i can only have 1 "loop"? as for which one, will be determined by the toggle button?

Comment: @yvonnezoe I would *recommend* just one loop. The way I show here also only updates monitor when needed (per event). It may look scary if you haven't seen some of it before, but it isn't so hard. :)

Comment: @yvonnezoe I added some comments - hopefully it's more clear now.

Comment: yes it does look scary! but thank you for explaining with comments :) btw, are there other alternatives beside `setinterval`?

Comment: @yvonnezoe Not that I am aware of. Of course, there is as you already use `setTimeout` which is *relative* compared to `setInterval` which is absolute (fixed intervals). (You do have more specialized mechanisms  such as `requestAnimationFrame`. However this is intended for canvas and calls 60 (or 30) per second and is not very useful in a scenario as this.)

Comment: can i ask something? i'm not sure if `monitor` is a standard variable for the customEvent? and as for the `detail: {` part, i'm not really sure what i should put in there.

Comment: @yvonnezoe That is correct. As this is a *CustomEvent* we can name it what we want as long as it doesn't collide with other events. It can be called 'updatemonitor' or 'yippikayei' or almost anything else :o). The important part (besides from name collisions) is that we *listen* to that same event name. In the detail section you can f.ex. put in *what* to update, or send progress, or anything the monitor need for updating (text, numbers, arrays, objects etc) from inside the loop. If you only do a generic update then this can be empty.

Comment: I'm not sure I agree with "You simply can't as they have no guarantee of order." The question suggests they're supposed to be totally independent of each other so the order should be irrelevant. Not knowing which order they'll execute in shouldn't be an issue.

Comment: @yvonnezoe updated example to use setTimeout instead - this is a better approach than setInterval.

Comment: Hi Ken, thank you so much for the great example. :D i shall do some self-study on customEvent as well.

Answer (score 1):

> How can I make sure any 2 setIntervals are isolated and will not affect each other?

**Variable scope**

Make sure that all of the variables involved are correctly scoped, and avoid adding any to the global scope unless it's completely unavoidable (this shouldn't be the case). This means you'll want to be using the `var` keyword whenever you declare any variables.

If your variables are correctly scoped to their respective `setInterval` calls then there's no danger of one affecting values in the other, even if you've used the same variable names.

**Check your logic**

If you're querying, and then modifying, the same set of elements on the page in both of them then they can't be independent, since changes in one of them will then be reflected in the next execution of the other one. Any shared logic, any use of global variables, etc. are all potential candidates for issues to be introduced.

Essentially you're looking for any overlap between the two, and then (hopefully) eliminating that. If it *can't* be eliminated then your two setIntervals can't be isolated, and you either have to accept that the two are linked or find another approach to solving the problem.

Comment: HI Anthony, thank you for your explanation. you may be right, the 2 setIntervals will post to the same python function and they may be clashing at some point. and i'm not using local variable as well because i have events/conditions outside the function that will clear the timer... anyway, i've eliminated the 2nd setInterval to save all the hassle.

Answer (score 0):

How are the intervals triggered?

Maybe you can try to call them in for example a click function:

```
$('<ELEMENT>').click( function() {
    setInterval(function(){

    },3000);
});

$('<ELEMENT>').click( function() {
    setInterval(function () {

             var checked = $('#status_table tr [id^="monitor_"]:checked');
            if (checked.index()===-1 ||checked.length===0){
                clearloop(bigloop);
                $('#monitor').button('enable');
            }else{
                    //$('#monitor').button('enable'); //enable the monitor button
                    (function loop(i) {                           
                        //monitor element at index i
                        monitoring($(checked[i]).parents('tr'));
                        //delay of 3 seconds
                        setTimeout(function () {
                            //when incremented i is less than the number of rows, call loop for next index
                            if (++i < checked.length) loop(i);
                        }, 3000);
                    }(0)); //start with 0
            }                            
        }, index*3000); //loop period
});
```

Comment: umm yes they are called that way, i've added full codes :) thank you!